# Solving a cryptarithm

Tags: equation-solving, puzzle

[This problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2171999/i-dont-understand-the-homework-of-my-little-sister-do-you) appears on the mathematics stackexchange, which I summarize here as:

12 letters (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, k, l, m, n), are used to represent single digits, i.e., {0-9}. Given the following:

- d e f + f e f = g h h
- k l m + k l m = n k l
- a b c + a b c + a b c = b b b

There are a finite number of possibilities, so we can march through them and test, but is there smarter way to find the digits?

A naive application of `Solve` shows a trivial solution:

```
Solve[{3 c == Last@IntegerDigits[x],
       Last@IntegerDigits[x] == b, 
       3 b + First@IntegerDigits[x] == Last@IntegerDigits[y], 
       Last@IntegerDigits[y] == b,
       3 a + First@IntegerDigits[y] == b},
      {a, b, c, x, y}]

(* {{a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0, x -> 0, y -> 0}} *)
```

What's the best way to use *Mathematica* to crack the code (identify the digits a through n)?

Comment: Sorry I don't use mathematica, but the question seems almost irrelevant. Since the 3 equations are independent it makes little sense. I agree that A, B, C is 1,4,8. But K,L,M,N can be 4,2,1,8 as well as 2,6,3,5 so , I don't get it at all especially the 333,666, business.... there are other more varied answers...
jim

Comment: @JimmyGee, I agree that this problem is frustrating if you are expecting it to make sense as a set of equations, but that's not really the point here ... this is a sort of [number puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbal_arithmetic).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
# /. Solve[{   10^2 d + 10 e + f + 10^2 f + 10 e + f == 10^2 g + 10 h + h,
            2 (10^2 k + 10 l + m) == 10^2 n + 10 k + l,
            3 (10^2 a + 10 b + c) == 10^2 b + 10 b + b} ~ Join ~
          Thread[0 <= # <= 9 &@#], #, Integers]& @ {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, k, l, m, n} 
    // Short[#, 6] &
```

> ```
>  {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 2},
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 6, 3, 5},
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 8, 7},
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 1, 8},
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0},
>   <<739>>, 
>  {1, 4, 8, 9, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
>  {1, 4, 8, 9, 0, 0, 9, 0, 1, 0, 5, 2},
>  {1, 4, 8, 9, 0, 0, 9, 0, 2, 6, 3, 5},
>  {1, 4, 8, 9, 0, 0, 9, 0, 3, 6, 8, 7},
>  {1, 4, 8, 9, 0, 0, 9, 0, 4, 2, 1, 8}}
> ```

It yields the result instantanously. Mind `Slot` ( `#`) appears here in the three contexts, thus we had to put the symbol `&` in appropriate places where the pure functions  end.

Comment: Note that the equations are independent and the solution space can be represented as a cartesian product. (+1)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks, I can make this code nicer, however `{a, b, d, f, g, k, n}` should start from `1` rather than form `0` thus it makes any improvement a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 7):

```
v = {100, 10, 1};

{#, Variables[List @@ #]} & /@
 {
  v.{d, e, f} + v.{f, e, f} == v.{g, h, h},
  2*v.{k, l, m} == v.{n, k, l},
  3*v.{a, b, c} == v.{b, b, b}
 }

FindInstance[Join[{#}, Thread[10 > #2 > 0]], #2, Integers] & @@@ %
```

> ```
> {{{d -> 3, e -> 3, f -> 3, g -> 6, h -> 6}},
>  {{k -> 2, l -> 6, m -> 3, n -> 5}},
>  {{a -> 1, b -> 4, c -> 8}}}
> ```

Comment: Very nice, this returns solution 543 from the full listing given by @Artes answer. Does `FindInstance` call `Solve` or something similar internally, or is it independent?

Comment: @dionys Good question.  I think it is independent but I have never really examined that.  Typically `Solve` looks for a pure analytic solution, but in a case like this it can enumerate numeric solutions as well, I believe using `Reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

Brute force:

```
lab = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "k", "l", "m", "n"};
tu[n_] := Tuples[Range[0, 9], n];
f1 = IntegerDigits[{#[[1]] + #[[3]], 2 #[[2]], 2 #[[3]]}.{100, 10, 
     1}] &
c1 = Select[tu[5], 
   Length[f1[#]] < 4 && 
     PadLeft[f1[#], 3] == {#[[4]], #[[5]], #[[5]]} &];
f2 = IntegerDigits[2 {#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]}.{100, 10, 1}] &
c2 =
  Select[tu[4], 
   Length[f2[#]] < 4 && 
     PadLeft[f2[#], 3] == {#[[4]], #[[1]], #[[2]]} &];
f3 = IntegerDigits[3 {#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]}.{100, 10, 1}] &;
c3 = Select[tu[3], 
   Length[f3[#]] < 4 && 
     PadLeft[f3[#], 3] == {#[[2]], #[[2]], #[[2]]} &];
ans = Catenate /@ Tuples[{c3, c1, c2}];
TableForm[ans[[-10 ;; -1]], TableHeadings -> {None, lab}]
```

The last 10 of the 750 answers:

[image]